# Trouble setting boolean value with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble setting a boolean to true using ng-model. When the user clicks on the radio button, Instead of changing the the boolean to true, the boolean is given the whole object.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in questions[counter].choices" class="answer">
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="{{choice}}" id="{{choice}}" ng-model="choice.selected" ng-value="true"/>
  <label class="radio" for="{{choice}}">
    {{choice.selected}}
    <h3>{{choice.text}}</h3>
  </label>
</div>
```

And the object:

```
    $scope.questions = [
        {
        question: "Question1 text",
        choices: [
          {id: 1, text: "choice 1", correct: true,  selected: false},
          {id: 2, text: "choice 2", correct: false, selected: false},
          {id: 3, text: "choice 3", correct: false, selected: false},
          {id: 4, text: "choice 4", correct: false, selected: false}
        ]
    },
        {
        question: "Question2 text",
        choices: [
          {id: 1, text: "choice 1", correct: true,  selected: false},
          {id: 2, text: "choice 2", correct: false, selected: false},
          {id: 3, text: "choice 3", correct: false, selected: false},
          {id: 4, text: "choice 4", correct: false, selected: false}
        ]
    }
];
```

And here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nGeNTAEvor0gspiJZSn7?p=preview).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i believe you want to change it to `value="{{choice.selected}}"`
Check this: http://plnkr.co/edit/4LM2zN?p=preview

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Nayish I'm trying to do a quiz app, so I want the property of selected to become true when the user selects that radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your input to the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="{{choice}}"
ng-model="choice.selected" ng-value="true" ng-change="updateOptions(questions[counter].choices,choice);"/>
```

And add this function to your controller:

```
  $scope.updateOptions = function(choices, choice){
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
      choices[i].selected = choices[i].id==choice.id;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That works perfectly! So ng-change listens for changes to the ng-model?

Comment: No, it listens for the changes to the radio input button. The function takes care of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons don't evaluate to true/false values, they evaluate to the objects they are bound to. If you want true/false values, use checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{choice.text}}" ng-model="choice.selected" ng-value="true"/>
```

Comment: This works great. But is there an option using radio buttons? Because I want to limit users to pick one answer.